# Show wordpress as category is selected without reload

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm developing a wordpress theme and I have this situation.

[image: Site]

For each category link I made a custom wordpress loop, displaying only posts in that category.

When a user clicks on some link (category), I want that space to show that loop without reloading the page.

How can I do this?

This is the static layout:
http://viniciusbarcelos.com.br/yosuki/delivery.php

Sorry for my bad English, I'm Brazilian!

Really thanks!

Comment: That would require AJAX. You need to read a bit about how to structure your site so that it can handle an AJAX request.

Comment: As far as I understand you want the user to see the details for the food without refreshing the page? This can be done via AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest approach would be: make it first work with reloading. Then you could use some jQuery to enchance user expierience by ajax call (example):

```
$('.menu-delivery a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var $el = $(this);

   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: $el.attr('href')
   }.done(function (data) {
     var $new = $(data).find('.delivery-individual');
     $('.delivery-individual').remove();
     $('.cardapio-delivery').append($new);
  });
}
```

That will be not the best performance-wise solution, but very easy to achieve.